# In MySQL, with FKs what's "CONSTRAINT" do?

Tags: mysql, ddl, referential-integrity

I've looked at the MySQL 5.1 docs, and still can't figured this out -- that being I noticed a difference between the code I input into MySQL and output code by the system.

**What is the difference between the code sample 01 and 02, meaning 02 has added `CONSTRAINT` before `FOREIGN KEY` -- why, and what's it do?**

**CODE_SAMPLE_01:**

```
FOREIGN KEY (TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK) REFERENCES TABLE_01(TABLE_01_sID_PK),
```

**CONTEXT:**

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_02` (
  `TABLE_02_sID_PK` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_cID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_data01` varchar(128) default NULL,
  `TABLE_02_data02` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `create_timestamp` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TABLE_02_sID_PK`),
  FOREIGN KEY (TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK) REFERENCES TABLE_01(TABLE_01_sID_PK),
  INDEX `TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK` (`TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**CODE_SAMPLE_02:**

```
CONSTRAINT `table_02_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK`) REFERENCES `table_01` (`TABLE_01_sID_PK`)
```

**CONTEXT:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table_02` (
  `TABLE_02_sID_PK` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_cID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_data01` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_02_data02` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `create_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TABLE_02_sID_PK`),
  KEY `TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK` (`TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK`),
  CONSTRAINT `table_02_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TABLE_02_nID_FK__TABLE_01_sID_PK`) REFERENCES `table_01` (`TABLE_01_sID_PK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The optional CONSTRAINT keyword allows you to specify a name for the foreign key. Without it, a name will be generated automatically.

This name can be seen in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) table.

Comment: Thanks, nice clear answer in regards to what it is, though I have no idea what the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is; I look at the link you provided, and it's parent links in the breadcrumbs on MySQL. Is that a database for the database? Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a virtual database in MySQL. `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`

Comment: Very cool, thanks -- your answers were a huge help! (+2, plus selected as the answer)

Comment: @blunders: +2? You must be a fellow Chicagoan voting twice like that! :-)

Comment: +1 one more... too funny, and Chicago's freaking cold, bundle up.