# What is the use of CONSTRAINT keyword when adding a Foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I Can't figure out what is the difference between these two.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES ..
```

and

```
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES ..
```

Is it just naming, or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MySQL, with FKs what's "CONSTRAINT" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349881/in-mysql-with-fks-whats-constraint-do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As MySQL manual on [foreign keys indicates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), the `CONSTRAINT symbol_name` part of the constraint syntax is optional:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
[index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
[ON DELETE reference_option]
[ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

The difference is in the naming of the foreign key. As the above linked document describes:

> Otherwise, MySQL implicitly creates a foreign key index that is named according to the following rules:
>
> • If defined, the CONSTRAINT symbol value is used. Otherwise, the
>   FOREIGN KEY index_name value is used.
>
> • If neither a CONSTRAINT symbol or FOREIGN KEY index_name is defined,
>   the foreign key index name is generated using the name of the
>   referencing foreign key column.

Answer (score 4):

With the `CONSTRAINT` clause you can define a constraint name for the foreign key constraint. If missing MySQL will generate a name automatically.